# Java beginner Question: Can a method be called inside it self?

Tags: java, recursion

I had an exam today and there was a question which I don't really remember the exact code.

But what I do remember that inside the `method exampleMethod(int num)` there was a line calling the method itself inside the method.

**I want to know can a method be called inside it self? because it was a multiple choice question and they wanted from us to find the output.**

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks SOF :)

Comment: Why don't you write a small program to try it out yourself? Experimenting is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure it can.  When you do that it's called *recursion*.  Be careful that you have an exit condition or you will get a stack overflow.

for example

```
int iAmRecursive(int num) {
   if (num > 10) // break out at some condition; i.e. don't recurse
       return num; // return so the recursion doesn't continue

   iAmRecursive(num + 1); // I didn't break out, so continue to recurse.
}
```

EDIT -- here is the same example but with a different break-out, to compliment @Ted's comment

```
int iAmRecursive(int num) {
   if (num <= 10) // only continue under certain condition
       iAmRecursive(num + 1); 

   // When I get here, I implicitly break out by not recursing.
}
```

however I prefer to always be as explicit as possible, so I would explicitly break out as in the first example, if possible.

Comment: Hmm... There was no exit condition inside the code.  I'm trying so hard to remember the question :S

Comment: +1 for using "stack overflow" (as well as for a correct answer).

Comment: @ted, yeah, i couldn't resist ;)

Comment: @Mohammad - an "exit condition" is any test in the body of the method that would prevent the recursive call if the condition were met. For instance: `int factorial(n) { return n < 2 ? 1 : n * factorial(n-1); }`

Comment: Oh boy! I got this question wrong! how come I've never read it in my book

Comment: @Mohammad: Your book doesn't mention recursion? That's a pretty poor book on programming...

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder I maybe mistaken though. Anyway this question cost me 5points. Just got my grade and it was 95/110. thanks again guys!

Answer (score 2):

A nice example of recursion is a method to compute a factorial.

```
public static long factorial(int i)
{
    if (i == 1) return 1;
    return factorial(i - 1) * i;
}
```

Then invoke it simply like this:

```
long f = factorial(10); // equals 10! = 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 (* 1)
```

Comment: "faculty"? Most people know this as "factorial".

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I'm dutch. It "faculty" sounds good to me. Thanks for noticing it.